# vba common Next without for Error

Tags: vba

Below is a very simple code with many if statements that gives a "Next without for" error. I know that this error is expected when a statement is not closed, but I check and recheck the code and everything seems fine. The characters you cant identify is just string values in greek.
Thanks in advance for any given help

```
Sub sygr()
Dim aCell
Dim ThisRng As Range
Set ThisRng = Application.InputBox("Select a range", "Get Range", Type:=8)
For Each aCell In ThisRng
    If ActiveCell.Offset(rowOffset:=0, columnOffset:=-52).Value = "ÂÅ" Then
        If ActiveCell.Offset(rowOffset:=0, columnOffset:=-23).Value = "ÔÑ.Å4" And ActiveCell.Offset(rowOffset:=0, columnOffset:=-14).Value = "Á.Á.1" Then
            ActiveCell.Value = "2Á1"
        ElseIf ActiveCell.Offset(rowOffset:=0, columnOffset:=-24).Value = "Ä.Ì.1" And ActiveCell.Offset(rowOffset:=0, columnOffset:=-12).Value = "Ã.Á1" Then
            ActiveCell.Value = "2Á2"
        ElseIf ActiveCell.Offset(rowOffset:=0, columnOffset:=-23).Value = "ÔÑ.Å2" And ActiveCell.Offset(rowOffset:=0, columnOffset:=-12).Value = "Ã.Á1" Then
            ActiveCell.Value = "2Á3"
        ElseIf ActiveCell.Offset(rowOffset:=0, columnOffset:=-21).Value = "ÕÐ.Å3" And ActiveCell.Offset(rowOffset:=0, columnOffset:=-12).Value = "Ã.Á1" Then
            ActiveCell.Value = "2Á4"
        ElseIf ActiveCell.Offset(rowOffset:=0, columnOffset:=-20).Value = "Ä.Á1" And ActiveCell.Offset(rowOffset:=0, columnOffset:=-12).Value = "Ã.Á4" Then
            ActiveCell.Value = "2Á5"
        ElseIf ActiveCell.Offset(rowOffset:=0, columnOffset:=-45).Value = "ÕÏ2" And ActiveCell.Offset(rowOffset:=0, columnOffset:=-40).Value = "ÐË.Ï.ÐÅÑÉÖ.3" Then
            ActiveCell.Value = "2Â1"
        ElseIf ActiveCell.Offset(rowOffset:=0, columnOffset:=-45).Value = "ÕÏ2" And ActiveCell.Offset(rowOffset:=0, columnOffset:=-22).Value = "ÄÅ.Å4" Then
            ActiveCell.Value = "2Â2"
        ElseIf ActiveCell.Offset(rowOffset:=0, columnOffset:=-45).Value = "ÕÏ2" And ActiveCell.Offset(rowOffset:=0, columnOffset:=-20).Value = "Ä.Á4" Then
            ActiveCell.Value = "2Â3"
        ElseIf ActiveCell.Offset(rowOffset:=0, columnOffset:=-47).Value = "ÔÏ2" And ActiveCell.Offset(rowOffset:=0, columnOffset:=-3).Value = "Ð.Ï.3" Then
            ActiveCell.Value = "2Ã1"
        ElseIf ActiveCell.Offset(rowOffset:=0, columnOffset:=-45).Value = "ÕÏ2" And ActiveCell.Offset(rowOffset:=0, columnOffset:=-5).Value = "Ê.Ï.60.3" Then
            ActiveCell.Value = "2Ã2"
        ElseIf ActiveCell.Offset(rowOffset:=0, columnOffset:=-45).Value = "ÕÏ2" And ActiveCell.Offset(rowOffset:=0, columnOffset:=-3).Value = "Ð.Ï.3" Then
            ActiveCell.Value = "2Ã3"
        ElseIf ActiveCell.Offset(rowOffset:=0, columnOffset:=-40).Value = "ÐË.Ï.ÐÅÑÉÖ. 5" And ActiveCell.Offset(rowOffset:=0, columnOffset:=-7).Value = "Ê.Ï.19.1" Then
            ActiveCell.Value = "2Ã4"
        ElseIf ActiveCell.Offset(rowOffset:=0, columnOffset:=-40).Value = "ÐË.Ï.ÐÅÑÉÖ. 5" And ActiveCell.Offset(rowOffset:=0, columnOffset:=-6).Value = "Ê.Ï.45.4" Then
            ActiveCell.Value = "2Ã5"
        ElseIf ActiveCell.Offset(rowOffset:=0, columnOffset:=-40).Value = "ÐË.Ï.ÐÅÑÉÖ.1" And ActiveCell.Offset(rowOffset:=0, columnOffset:=-5).Value = "Ê.Ï.60.1" Then
            ActiveCell.Value = "2Ã6"
        Else
            ActiveCell.Value = "BE"
        End If
    ElseIf ActiveCell.Offset(rowOffset:=0, columnOffset:=-52).Value = "ÄÕÔ.Å" Then
        If ActiveCell.Offset(rowOffset:=0, columnOffset:=-24).Value = "Ä.Ì.1" And ActiveCell.Offset(rowOffset:=0, columnOffset:=-14).Value = "Á.Á.1" Then
            ActiveCell.Value = "3Á1"
        ElseIf ActiveCell.Offset(rowOffset:=0, columnOffset:=-22).Value = "ÄÅ.Å4" And ActiveCell.Offset(rowOffset:=0, columnOffset:=-14).Value = "Á.Á.1" Then
            ActiveCell.Value = "3Á2"
        ElseIf ActiveCell.Offset(rowOffset:=0, columnOffset:=-24).Value = "Ä.Ì.1" And ActiveCell.Offset(rowOffset:=0, columnOffset:=-12).Value = "Ã.Á2" Then
            ActiveCell.Value = "3Á3"
        ElseIf ActiveCell.Offset(rowOffset:=0, columnOffset:=-23).Value = "ÔÑ.Å4" And ActiveCell.Offset(rowOffset:=0, columnOffset:=-12).Value = "Ã.Á4" Then
            ActiveCell.Value = "3Á4"
        ElseIf ActiveCell.Offset(rowOffset:=0, columnOffset:=-22).Value = "ÄÅ.Å4" And ActiveCell.Offset(rowOffset:=0, columnOffset:=-12).Value = "Ã.Á4" Then
            ActiveCell.Value = "3Á5"
        ElseIf ActiveCell.Offset(rowOffset:=0, columnOffset:=-21).Value = "ÕÐ.Å4" And ActiveCell.Offset(rowOffset:=0, columnOffset:=-12).Value = "Ã.Á4" Then
            ActiveCell.Value = "3Á5"
        ElseIf ActiveCell.Offset(rowOffset:=0, columnOffset:=-47).Value = "ÔÏ3" And ActiveCell.Offset(rowOffset:=0, columnOffset:=-40).Value = "ÐË.Ï.ÐÅÑÉÖ.1" Then
            ActiveCell.Value = "3Â1"
        ElseIf ActiveCell.Offset(rowOffset:=0, columnOffset:=-47).Value = "ÔÏ1" And ActiveCell.Offset(rowOffset:=0, columnOffset:=-14).Value = "Á.Á.1" Then
            ActiveCell.Value = "3Â2"
        ElseIf ActiveCell.Offset(rowOffset:=0, columnOffset:=-47).Value = "ÔÏ3" And ActiveCell.Offset(rowOffset:=0, columnOffset:=-23).Value = "ÔÑ.Å2" Then
            ActiveCell.Value = "3Â3"
        ElseIf ActiveCell.Offset(rowOffset:=0, columnOffset:=-47).Value = "ÔÏ3" And ActiveCell.Offset(rowOffset:=0, columnOffset:=-22).Value = "ÄÅ.Å2" Then
            ActiveCell.Value = "3Â4"
        ElseIf ActiveCell.Offset(rowOffset:=0, columnOffset:=-47).Value = "ÔÏ3" And ActiveCell.Offset(rowOffset:=0, columnOffset:=-21).Value = "ÕÐ.Å2" Then
            ActiveCell.Value = "3Â5"
        ElseIf ActiveCell.Offset(rowOffset:=0, columnOffset:=-47).Value = "ÔÏ3" And ActiveCell.Offset(rowOffset:=0, columnOffset:=-20).Value = "Ä.Á2" Then
            ActiveCell.Value = "3Â6"
        ElseIf ActiveCell.Offset(rowOffset:=0, columnOffset:=-45).Value = "ÕÏ2" And ActiveCell.Offset(rowOffset:=0, columnOffset:=-40).Value = "ÐË.Ï.ÐÅÑÉÖ.3" Then
            ActiveCell.Value = "3Â7"
        ElseIf ActiveCell.Offset(rowOffset:=0, columnOffset:=-45).Value = "ÕÏ4" And ActiveCell.Offset(rowOffset:=0, columnOffset:=-24).Value = "Ä.Ì.1" Then
            ActiveCell.Value = "3Â8"
        ElseIf ActiveCell.Offset(rowOffset:=0, columnOffset:=-45).Value = "ÕÏ2" And ActiveCell.Offset(rowOffset:=0, columnOffset:=-23).Value = "ÔÑ.Å3" Then
            ActiveCell.Value = "3Â9"
        ElseIf ActiveCell.Offset(rowOffset:=0, columnOffset:=-45).Value = "ÕÏ4" And ActiveCell.Offset(rowOffset:=0, columnOffset:=-22).Value = "ÄÅ.Å2" Then
            ActiveCell.Value = "3Â10"
        ElseIf ActiveCell.Offset(rowOffset:=0, columnOffset:=-45).Value = "ÕÏ2" And ActiveCell.Offset(rowOffset:=0, columnOffset:=-21).Value = "ÕÐ.Å4" Then
            ActiveCell.Value = "3Â11"
        ElseIf ActiveCell.Offset(rowOffset:=0, columnOffset:=-45).Value = "ÕÏ2" And ActiveCell.Offset(rowOffset:=0, columnOffset:=-20).Value = "Ä.Á4" Then
            ActiveCell.Value = "3Â12"
        ElseIf ActiveCell.Offset(rowOffset:=0, columnOffset:=-47).Value = "ÔÏ1" And ActiveCell.Offset(rowOffset:=0, columnOffset:=-3).Value = "Ð.Ï.2" Then
            ActiveCell.Value = "3Ã1"
        ElseIf ActiveCell.Offset(rowOffset:=0, columnOffset:=-45).Value = "ÕÏ2" And ActiveCell.Offset(rowOffset:=0, columnOffset:=-3).Value = "Ð.Ï.2" Then
            ActiveCell.Value = "3Ã2"
        ElseIf ActiveCell.Offset(rowOffset:=0, columnOffset:=-45).Value = "ÕÏ2" And ActiveCell.Offset(rowOffset:=0, columnOffset:=-3).Value = "Ð.Ô.Ï.1" Then
            ActiveCell.Value = "3Ã3"
        ElseIf ActiveCell.Offset(rowOffset:=0, columnOffset:=-45).Value = "ÕÏ1" And ActiveCell.Offset(rowOffset:=0, columnOffset:=-1).Value = "Ð.Ð.×.Ï.1" Then
            ActiveCell.Value = "3Ã4"
        ElseIf ActiveCell.Offset(rowOffset:=0, columnOffset:=-3).Value = "Ð.Ï.1" And ActiveCell.Offset(rowOffset:=0, columnOffset:=-5).Value = "Ê.Ï.60.2" Then
            ActiveCell.Value = "3Ã5"
        ElseIf ActiveCell.Offset(rowOffset:=0, columnOffset:=-40).Value = "ÐË.Ï.ÐÅÑÉÖ.1" And ActiveCell.Offset(rowOffset:=0, columnOffset:=-7).Value = "Ê.Ï.19.1" Then
            ActiveCell.Value = "3Ã6"
        ElseIf ActiveCell.Offset(rowOffset:=0, columnOffset:=-40).Value = "ÐË.Ï.ÐÅÑÉÖ. 5" And ActiveCell.Offset(rowOffset:=0, columnOffset:=-6).Value = "Ê.Ï.45.4" Then
            ActiveCell.Value = "3Ã7"
        ElseIf ActiveCell.Offset(rowOffset:=0, columnOffset:=-40).Value = "ÐË.Ï.ÐÅÑÉÖ. 5" And ActiveCell.Offset(rowOffset:=0, columnOffset:=-5).Value = "Ê.Ï.60.4" Then
            ActiveCell.Value = "3Ã8"
        Else
            ActiveCell.Value = "ÄÕÔ.Å"
        End If
    ElseIf ActiveCell.Offset(rowOffset:=0, columnOffset:=-52).Value = "ÊÅ" Then
        If ActiveCell.Offset(rowOffset:=0, columnOffset:=-24).Value = "Ä.Ì.1" And ActiveCell.Offset(rowOffset:=0, columnOffset:=-12).Value = "Ã.Á1" Then
            ActiveCell.Value = "4Á1"
        ElseIf ActiveCell.Offset(rowOffset:=0, columnOffset:=-23).Value = "ÔÑ.Å1" And ActiveCell.Offset(rowOffset:=0, columnOffset:=-12).Value = "Ã.Á1" Then
            ActiveCell.Value = "4A2"
        ElseIf ActiveCell.Offset(rowOffset:=0, columnOffset:=-22).Value = "ÄÅ.Å1" And ActiveCell.Offset(rowOffset:=0, columnOffset:=-12).Value = "Ã.Á1" Then
            ActiveCell.Value = "4A3"
        ElseIf ActiveCell.Offset(rowOffset:=0, columnOffset:=-47).Value = "ÔÏ3" And ActiveCell.Offset(rowOffset:=0, columnOffset:=-40).Value = "ÐË.Ï.ÐÅÑÉÖ.1" Then
            ActiveCell.Value = "3Â1"
        ElseIf ActiveCell.Offset(rowOffset:=0, columnOffset:=-47).Value = "ÔÏ3" And ActiveCell.Offset(rowOffset:=0, columnOffset:=-24).Value = "Ä.Ì2" Then
            ActiveCell.Value = "3Â2"
        ElseIf ActiveCell.Offset(rowOffset:=0, columnOffset:=-47).Value = "ÔÏ2" And ActiveCell.Offset(rowOffset:=0, columnOffset:=-20).Value = "Ä.Á1" Then
            ActiveCell.Value = "3Â3"
        ElseIf ActiveCell.Offset(rowOffset:=0, columnOffset:=-45).Value = "ÕÏ2" And ActiveCell.Offset(rowOffset:=0, columnOffset:=-40).Value = "ÐË.Ï.ÐÅÑÉÖ.1" Then
            ActiveCell.Value = "3Â4"
        ElseIf ActiveCell.Offset(rowOffset:=0, columnOffset:=-45).Value = "ÕÏ2" And ActiveCell.Offset(rowOffset:=0, columnOffset:=-12).Value = "Ã.Á4" Then
            ActiveCell.Value = "3Â5"
        ElseIf ActiveCell.Offset(rowOffset:=0, columnOffset:=-45).Value = "ÕÏ2" And ActiveCell.Offset(rowOffset:=0, columnOffset:=-24).Value = "Ä.Ì.1" Then
            ActiveCell.Value = "3Â6"
        ElseIf ActiveCell.Offset(rowOffset:=0, columnOffset:=-45).Value = "ÕÏ2" And ActiveCell.Offset(rowOffset:=0, columnOffset:=-23).Value = "ÔÑ.Å1" Then
            ActiveCell.Value = "3Â7"
        ElseIf ActiveCell.Offset(rowOffset:=0, columnOffset:=-45).Value = "ÕÏ2" And ActiveCell.Offset(rowOffset:=0, columnOffset:=-22).Value = "ÄÅ.Å1" Then
            ActiveCell.Value = "3Â9"
        ElseIf ActiveCell.Offset(rowOffset:=0, columnOffset:=-45).Value = "ÕÏ2" And ActiveCell.Offset(rowOffset:=0, columnOffset:=-21).Value = "ÕÐ.Å1" Then
            ActiveCell.Value = "3Â10"
        ElseIf ActiveCell.Offset(rowOffset:=0, columnOffset:=-45).Value = "ÕÏ2" And ActiveCell.Offset(rowOffset:=0, columnOffset:=-20).Value = "Ä.Á1" Then
            ActiveCell.Value = "3Â11"
        ElseIf ActiveCell.Offset(rowOffset:=0, columnOffset:=-47).Value = "ÔÏ1" And ActiveCell.Offset(rowOffset:=0, columnOffset:=-3).Value = "Ð.Ï.2" Then
            ActiveCell.Value = "3Ã1"
        ElseIf ActiveCell.Offset(rowOffset:=0, columnOffset:=-45).Value = "ÕÏ2" And ActiveCell.Offset(rowOffset:=0, columnOffset:=-3).Value = "Ð.Ï.2" Then
            ActiveCell.Value = "3Ã2"
        ElseIf ActiveCell.Offset(rowOffset:=0, columnOffset:=-45).Value = "ÕÏ2" And ActiveCell.Offset(rowOffset:=0, columnOffset:=-3).Value = "Ð.Ô.Ï.1" Then
            ActiveCell.Value = "3Ã3"
        ElseIf ActiveCell.Offset(rowOffset:=0, columnOffset:=-45).Value = "ÕÏ1" And ActiveCell.Offset(rowOffset:=0, columnOffset:=-1).Value = "Ð.Ð.×.Ï.1" Then
            ActiveCell.Value = "3Ã4"
        ElseIf ActiveCell.Offset(rowOffset:=0, columnOffset:=-3).Value = "Ð.Ï.1" And ActiveCell.Offset(rowOffset:=0, columnOffset:=-5).Value = "Ê.Ï.60.2" Then
            ActiveCell.Value = "3Ã5"
        ElseIf ActiveCell.Offset(rowOffset:=0, columnOffset:=-40).Value = "ÐË.Ï.ÐÅÑÉÖ.1" And ActiveCell.Offset(rowOffset:=0, columnOffset:=-7).Value = "Ê.Ï.19.1" Then
            ActiveCell.Value = "3Ã6"
        ElseIf ActiveCell.Offset(rowOffset:=0, columnOffset:=-40).Value = "ÐË.Ï.ÐÅÑÉÖ. 5" And ActiveCell.Offset(rowOffset:=0, columnOffset:=-6).Value = "Ê.Ï.45.4" Then
            ActiveCell.Value = "3Ã7"
        ElseIf ActiveCell.Offset(rowOffset:=0, columnOffset:=-40).Value = "ÐË.Ï.ÐÅÑÉÖ. 5" And ActiveCell.Offset(rowOffset:=0, columnOffset:=-5).Value = "Ê.Ï.60.4" Then
            ActiveCell.Value = "3Ã8"
        Else
            ActiveCell.Value = "ÊÅ"
        End If
    ElseIf ActiveCell.Offset(rowOffset:=0, columnOffset:=-52).Value = "ÍÏÔ.Å" Then
        If ActiveCell.Offset(rowOffset:=0, columnOffset:=-24).Value = "Ä.Ì.1" And ActiveCell.Offset(rowOffset:=0, columnOffset:=-12).Value = "Ã.Á1" Then
            ActiveCell.Value = "5Á1"
        ElseIf ActiveCell.Offset(rowOffset:=0, columnOffset:=-23).Value = "ÔÑ.Å1" And ActiveCell.Offset(rowOffset:=0, columnOffset:=-12).Value = "Ã.Á1" Then
            ActiveCell.Value = "5A2"
        ElseIf ActiveCell.Offset(rowOffset:=0, columnOffset:=-22).Value = "ÄÅ.Å1" And ActiveCell.Offset(rowOffset:=0, columnOffset:=-12).Value = "Ã.Á1" Then
            ActiveCell.Value = "5A3"
        ElseIf ActiveCell.Offset(rowOffset:=0, columnOffset:=-47).Value = "ÔÏ3" And ActiveCell.Offset(rowOffset:=0, columnOffset:=-40).Value = "ÐË.Ï.ÐÅÑÉÖ.1" Then
            ActiveCell.Value = "5Â1"
        ElseIf ActiveCell.Offset(rowOffset:=0, columnOffset:=-47).Value = "ÔÏ3" And ActiveCell.Offset(rowOffset:=0, columnOffset:=-24).Value = "Ä.Ì2" Then
            ActiveCell.Value = "5Â2"
        ElseIf ActiveCell.Offset(rowOffset:=0, columnOffset:=-47).Value = "ÔÏ2" And ActiveCell.Offset(rowOffset:=0, columnOffset:=-20).Value = "Ä.Á1" Then
            ActiveCell.Value = "5Â3"
        ElseIf ActiveCell.Offset(rowOffset:=0, columnOffset:=-45).Value = "ÕÏ2" And ActiveCell.Offset(rowOffset:=0, columnOffset:=-40).Value = "ÐË.Ï.ÐÅÑÉÖ.1" Then
            ActiveCell.Value = "5Â4"
        ElseIf ActiveCell.Offset(rowOffset:=0, columnOffset:=-45).Value = "ÕÏ2" And ActiveCell.Offset(rowOffset:=0, columnOffset:=-12).Value = "Ã.Á4" Then
            ActiveCell.Value = "5Â5"
        ElseIf ActiveCell.Offset(rowOffset:=0, columnOffset:=-45).Value = "ÕÏ2" And ActiveCell.Offset(rowOffset:=0, columnOffset:=-24).Value = "Ä.Ì.1" Then
            ActiveCell.Value = "5Â6"
        ElseIf ActiveCell.Offset(rowOffset:=0, columnOffset:=-45).Value = "ÕÏ2" And ActiveCell.Offset(rowOffset:=0, columnOffset:=-23).Value = "ÔÑ.Å1" Then
            ActiveCell.Value = "5Â7"
        ElseIf ActiveCell.Offset(rowOffset:=0, columnOffset:=-45).Value = "ÕÏ2" And ActiveCell.Offset(rowOffset:=0, columnOffset:=-22).Value = "ÄÅ.Å1" Then
            ActiveCell.Value = "5Â9"
        ElseIf ActiveCell.Offset(rowOffset:=0, columnOffset:=-45).Value = "ÕÏ2" And ActiveCell.Offset(rowOffset:=0, columnOffset:=-21).Value = "ÕÐ.Å1" Then
            ActiveCell.Value = "5Â10"
        ElseIf ActiveCell.Offset(rowOffset:=0, columnOffset:=-45).Value = "ÕÏ2" And ActiveCell.Offset(rowOffset:=0, columnOffset:=-20).Value = "Ä.Á1" Then
            ActiveCell.Value = "5Â11"
        ElseIf ActiveCell.Offset(rowOffset:=0, columnOffset:=-47).Value = "ÔÏ3" And ActiveCell.Offset(rowOffset:=0, columnOffset:=-6).Value = "Ê.Ï.45.1" Then
            ActiveCell.Value = "5Ã1"
        ElseIf ActiveCell.Offset(rowOffset:=0, columnOffset:=-47).Value = "ÔÏ3" And ActiveCell.Offset(rowOffset:=0, columnOffset:=-5).Value = "Ê.Ï.60.1" Then
            ActiveCell.Value = "5Ã2"
        ElseIf ActiveCell.Offset(rowOffset:=0, columnOffset:=-47).Value = "ÔÏ3" And ActiveCell.Offset(rowOffset:=0, columnOffset:=-3).Value = "Ð.Ï.3" Then
            ActiveCell.Value = "5Ã3"
        ElseIf ActiveCell.Offset(rowOffset:=0, columnOffset:=-47).Value = "ÔÏ3" And ActiveCell.Offset(rowOffset:=0, columnOffset:=-1).Value = "Ð.Ð.×.Ï. 3" Then
            ActiveCell.Value = "5Ã4"
        ElseIf ActiveCell.Offset(rowOffset:=0, columnOffset:=-45).Value = "ÕÏ2" And ActiveCell.Offset(rowOffset:=0, columnOffset:=-7).Value = "Ê.Ï.19.2" Then
            ActiveCell.Value = "5Ã5"
        ElseIf ActiveCell.Offset(rowOffset:=0, columnOffset:=-45).Value = "ÕÏ2" And ActiveCell.Offset(rowOffset:=0, columnOffset:=-6).Value = "Ê.Ï.45.1" Then
            ActiveCell.Value = "5Ã6"
        ElseIf ActiveCell.Offset(rowOffset:=0, columnOffset:=-45).Value = "ÕÏ1" And ActiveCell.Offset(rowOffset:=0, columnOffset:=-5).Value = "Ê.Ï.60.4" Then
            ActiveCell.Value = "5Ã7"
        ElseIf ActiveCell.Offset(rowOffset:=0, columnOffset:=-45).Value = "ÕÏ2" And ActiveCell.Offset(rowOffset:=0, columnOffset:=-3).Value = "Ð.Ï.1" Then
            ActiveCell.Value = "5Ã8"
        ElseIf ActiveCell.Offset(rowOffset:=0, columnOffset:=-45).Value = "ÕÏ2" And ActiveCell.Offset(rowOffset:=0, columnOffset:=-1).Value = "Ð.Ð.×.Ï.1" Then
            ActiveCell.Value = "5Ã9"
        ElseIf ActiveCell.Offset(rowOffset:=0, columnOffset:=-3).Value = "Ð.Ï.1" And ActiveCell.Offset(rowOffset:=0, columnOffset:=-6).Value = "Ê.Ï.45.1" Then
            ActiveCell.Value = "5Ã10"
        ElseIf ActiveCell.Offset(rowOffset:=0, columnOffset:=-1).Value = "Ð.Ð.×.Ï.1" And ActiveCell.Offset(rowOffset:=0, columnOffset:=-6).Value = "Ê.Ï.45.1" Then
            ActiveCell.Value = "5Ã11"
        ElseIf ActiveCell.Offset(rowOffset:=0, columnOffset:=-3).Value = "Ð.Ï.1" And ActiveCell.Offset(rowOffset:=0, columnOffset:=-5).Value = "Ê.Ï.60.1" Then
            ActiveCell.Value = "5Ã12"
        ElseIf ActiveCell.Offset(rowOffset:=0, columnOffset:=-40).Value = "ÐË.Ï.ÐÅÑÉÖ.1" And ActiveCell.Offset(rowOffset:=0, columnOffset:=-7).Value = "Ê.Ï.19.3" Then
            ActiveCell.Value = "5Ã13"
        ElseIf ActiveCell.Offset(rowOffset:=0, columnOffset:=-40).Value = "ÐË.Ï.ÐÅÑÉÖ.1" And ActiveCell.Offset(rowOffset:=0, columnOffset:=-6).Value = "Ê.Ï.45.1" Then
            ActiveCell.Value = "5Ã14"
        ElseIf ActiveCell.Offset(rowOffset:=0, columnOffset:=-40).Value = "ÐË.Ï.ÐÅÑÉÖ. 5" And ActiveCell.Offset(rowOffset:=0, columnOffset:=-5).Value = "Ê.Ï.60.4" Then
            ActiveCell.Value = "5Ã15"
        ElseIf ActiveCell.Offset(rowOffset:=0, columnOffset:=-37).Value = "Ï.Ì.2" And ActiveCell.Offset(rowOffset:=0, columnOffset:=-7).Value = "Ê.Ï.19.3" Then
            ActiveCell.Value = "5Ã16"
        ElseIf ActiveCell.Offset(rowOffset:=0, columnOffset:=-37).Value = "Ï.Ì.5" And ActiveCell.Offset(rowOffset:=0, columnOffset:=-6).Value = "Ê.Ï.45.1" Then
            ActiveCell.Value = "5Ã17"
        ElseIf ActiveCell.Offset(rowOffset:=0, columnOffset:=-37).Value = "Ï.Ì.3" And ActiveCell.Offset(rowOffset:=0, columnOffset:=-5).Value = "Ê.Ï.60.4" Then
            ActiveCell.Value = "5Ã18"
        Else
            ActiveCell.Value = "ÍÏÔ.Å"
        End If
    ElseIf ActiveCell.Offset(rowOffset:=0, columnOffset:=-52).Value = "ÍÏÔ.Å" Then
        If ActiveCell.Offset(rowOffset:=0, columnOffset:=-24).Value = "Ä.Ì.1" And ActiveCell.Offset(rowOffset:=0, columnOffset:=-14).Value = "Á.Á.1" Then
            ActiveCell.Value = "6Á1"
        If ActiveCell.Offset(rowOffset:=0, columnOffset:=-23).Value = "ÔÑ.Å4" And ActiveCell.Offset(rowOffset:=0, columnOffset:=-14).Value = "Á.Á.1" Then
            ActiveCell.Value = "6Á2"
        ElseIf ActiveCell.Offset(rowOffset:=0, columnOffset:=-22).Value = "ÄÅ.Å4" And ActiveCell.Offset(rowOffset:=0, columnOffset:=-14).Value = "Á.Á.1" Then
            ActiveCell.Value = "6Á3"
        ElseIf ActiveCell.Offset(rowOffset:=0, columnOffset:=-21).Value = "ÕÐ.Å4" And ActiveCell.Offset(rowOffset:=0, columnOffset:=-14).Value = "Á.Á.1" Then
            ActiveCell.Value = "6Á4"
        ElseIf ActiveCell.Offset(rowOffset:=0, columnOffset:=-20).Value = "Ä.Á3" And ActiveCell.Offset(rowOffset:=0, columnOffset:=-14).Value = "Á.Á.1" Then
            ActiveCell.Value = "6Á5"
        ElseIf ActiveCell.Offset(rowOffset:=0, columnOffset:=-24).Value = "Ä.Ì.1" And ActiveCell.Offset(rowOffset:=0, columnOffset:=-13).Value = "Â.Á1" Then
            ActiveCell.Value = "6Á6"
        ElseIf ActiveCell.Offset(rowOffset:=0, columnOffset:=-23).Value = "ÔÑ.Å3" And ActiveCell.Offset(rowOffset:=0, columnOffset:=-13).Value = "Â.Á1" Then
            ActiveCell.Value = "6Á7"
        ElseIf ActiveCell.Offset(rowOffset:=0, columnOffset:=-22).Value = "ÄÅ.Å3" And ActiveCell.Offset(rowOffset:=0, columnOffset:=-13).Value = "Â.Á1" Then
            ActiveCell.Value = "6Á8"
        ElseIf ActiveCell.Offset(rowOffset:=0, columnOffset:=-21).Value = "ÕÐ.Å3" And ActiveCell.Offset(rowOffset:=0, columnOffset:=-13).Value = "Â.Á1" Then
            ActiveCell.Value = "6Á9"
        ElseIf ActiveCell.Offset(rowOffset:=0, columnOffset:=-24).Value = "Ä.Á3" And ActiveCell.Offset(rowOffset:=0, columnOffset:=-13).Value = "Â.Á1" Then
            ActiveCell.Value = "6Á10"
        ElseIf ActiveCell.Offset(rowOffset:=0, columnOffset:=-24).Value = "Ä.Ì.1" And ActiveCell.Offset(rowOffset:=0, columnOffset:=-12).Value = "Ã.Á1" Then
            ActiveCell.Value = "6Á11"
        ElseIf ActiveCell.Offset(rowOffset:=0, columnOffset:=-23).Value = "ÔÑ.Å1" And ActiveCell.Offset(rowOffset:=0, columnOffset:=-12).Value = "Ã.Á1" Then
            ActiveCell.Value = "6Á12"
        ElseIf ActiveCell.Offset(rowOffset:=0, columnOffset:=-22).Value = "ÄÅ.Å1" And ActiveCell.Offset(rowOffset:=0, columnOffset:=-12).Value = "Ã.Á1" Then
            ActiveCell.Value = "6Á13"
        ElseIf ActiveCell.Offset(rowOffset:=0, columnOffset:=-21).Value = "ÕÐ.Å1" And ActiveCell.Offset(rowOffset:=0, columnOffset:=-12).Value = "Ã.Á1" Then
            ActiveCell.Value = "6Á14"
        ElseIf ActiveCell.Offset(rowOffset:=0, columnOffset:=-20).Value = "Ä.Á3" And ActiveCell.Offset(rowOffset:=0, columnOffset:=-12).Value = "Ã.Á3" Then
            ActiveCell.Value = "6Á15"
        Else
            ActiveCell.Value = "ÍÇÓ.Å"
        End If
    Else
    'Do nothing
    End If
Next aCell
```

End Sub

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 2 times "If" right after each other, down in fifth big ElseIf section.

Comment: Thanks a lot man! case closed here. I had read it so many times... 
PS Just for the record, the correct code requires also 'aCell.Activate' after for each row.